# Number of current threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The problem is when I ran code

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
    }
```

it was 2 instead of 1 I thought it would be.
Why there 2 running threads? Cause I thought there is 1 thread, so called main thread in method main

Comment: There might be plenty of background threads. Try `for(Thread t:Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) System.out.println(t);` to see what there is in your case.

Comment: @Holger That will surely give more than OP's two threads.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: but you can see which threads belong to the same thread group from the output.

Answer (score 3):

There can be any number of worker threads for the JVM itself, for example the GC thread(s).

Answer (score 3):

[Thread#activeCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount()) return number of active threads in current thread group. The thread group of `main thread` is called `main` and in the same group there is another thread called `Monitor Ctrl-Break,` . That's why Thread.activeCount returns 2 in your case. Note that this behavior is platform specific.
You can use

```
Set<Thread> set = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

to get live threads and iterater over them to see details about them, like this

```
for (Thread thread : set) {
    System.out.println(thread.getName() + ", "+ thread.getThreadGroup());
}
```

Comment: This may be platform-specific, on OS X I get a single thread counted. But in any case, this is the only answer that even *attempts* to address the actual question, +1.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik tx, yes indeed it is platform specific. I ran the code on linux. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know what's going on with all the threads,

```
  public static void logThreadDumps() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32768);
    sb.append("============ THREAD DUMP ============\n");
    ThreadInfo[] threads = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true);
    for (ThreadInfo info : threads) {
      sb.append(info);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());  // or log it
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.activeCount();
```

Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group and its subgroups. Recursively iterates over all subgroups in the current thread's thread group.

`The value returned is only an estimate because the number of threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain system threads.`

Visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount()